# How to pass the fetched tweet(tweepy.StreamListener) into html page using django

Tags: python, django

I want to create a web page which should **scrape** twitter to fetch user data by given location
I am using tweepy's StreamListener to fetch tweet by location but i don't know how to pass that to html page using render in django

MyListerner class is fetching the tweets but its not returning the fetched tweet

I want to fetch tweets by given location and pass that into html file

when I tried to render the page inside MyStreamListener class I couldn't pass request value in on_status Error : undefined parameter request inside filter() method

Without passing request inside filter its raising on_status missing one argumet request and without defining request parameter in on_status i couldn't render the template Error : join() should not contain dict value

Is there any proper way to return the fetched tweet into django template

```
class Authenticator:

    def authenticate_and_get_API_object(self):
        apiKey = ""
        apiSecretKey = ""
        accessToken = ""
        accessTokenSecret = ""
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apiKey, apiSecretKey)
        auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        return api


class MyStreamListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.limit = 5

    def on_status(self, status):

        api = Authenticator().authenticate_and_get_API_object()

        if (time.time() - self.start_time) < self.limit:

            tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, count=10, q="python", lang="en", since='2021-03-18').items(100)

            count = 1

            return tweets


        else:
            return False

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
        return False


class TweetScraper(View):
 
    def get(self, request):
    
        locForm = LocationForm()
        args = {"locForm": locForm}
        return render(request, 'tweetScraper/tweetscraper.html', args)

    def post(self, request):
        tweet_list = []
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            locForm = LocationForm(request.POST or None)
            formLoc = locForm.data
            if 'listBox' in request.POST and 'secondlist' in request.POST:
                location = formLoc['secondlist']
                try:

                    # Specify the user_agent as your
                    # app name it should not be none
                    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="your_app_name")
                    loc = geolocator.geocode(location)
                
                    print(loc.latitude)
                    print(loc.longitude)
                    location = [loc.latitude,loc.longitude]
                    print(location)

                
                    the_api = Authenticator().authenticate_and_get_API_object()
                    myStream = Stream(auth=the_api.auth, listener=TweetScraper(), secure=True, )
                    myStream.filter(track=["BJP"])

                    myStream.filter(locations=location)

                    tweets = MyStreamListener.on_status()



                except GeocoderTimedOut:
                    return 0

            else:
               False
            locForm = LocationForm()

        args = {"tweets":tweets,"locForm": locForm}

        return render(request, 'tweetScraper/tweetscraper.html', args)
```

Comment: You **should NOT** include your API keys in your question. This means I could just take them and have full access to your account. You should edit and remove them and also regenrate them as someone may try to use them now.

Comment: Thanks man.... , I have regenerate it and reset my twiiter account password , I didn't notice that in stress , I forgot to remove

Comment: No problem :) Good luck with the question!